# Resize Excel Table to a default setting

Tags: excel, vba, resize

I am trying to resize an Excel table to standard setting of 4 rows and 6 columns
I am able to do for the columns but I still see the empty rows based on the content earlier.

```
Sub ClearTableContents()
Dim wrksht As Worksheet
Dim objListObj As ListObjects
Dim tableName As String
Dim ActiveTable As ListObject

Dim ActiveRange As Range

Set wrksht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set objListObj = wrksht.ListObjects
With objListObj
  For i = 1 To objListObj.Count
     tableName = objListObj(i).Name
     Set ActiveTable = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(tableName)
     'ActiveTable.DataBodyRange.Rows.ClearContents
     objListObj(i).DataBodyRange.Rows.ClearContents
     On Error Resume Next
     'objListObj(i).DataBodyRange.Resize(objListObj(i).DataBodyRange.Rows.Count - 4, 
     objListObj(i).DataBodyRange.Columns.Count - 6).Rows.Delete
     objListObj(i).DataBodyRange.Resize(4, 6).Rows.Delete
     If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      ' process Error
       MsgBox "Error: (" & Err.Number & ") " & Err.Description, vbCritical
     End If

     Next i
   End With

  End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will leave the header and three rows so adjust to suit.

```
Sub x()

With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
    .Range.Rows("5:" & .Range.Rows.Count).Delete
    .Resize .Range.Resize(4, 6)
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. integrated your code in my code and its working perfectly fine.. Now i have another challenge. In one of my excel sheet there are two adjacent tables with 12 columns each. When the code runs for that sheet it creates a gap of 6 columns. I need a function to resize 1st table based on the contents fetched from the data base in such a way that the 2nd tables shift left or right based on the 1st table size.

Comment: Perhaps you could accept this answer and then start a new question for your other thing.